# strange issue of jquery mobile page reference and click function

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, jquery-mobile

I have this strange issue, if go to my index.html page(Website built with jQuery Mobile) which has a form with a button, then it's possible for me to click multiple times on the button which will generate an alert(to see if button is working) and also go to another page called main.html. I receive the alert when I click the button and I also go to the other page. Now if i go to main.html and then back again to the index.html and click the button again then it won't produce an alert nor goes back to the main.html page..

I have the following code for the button:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {    
     //event handler for submit button
     $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
          alert('fdfs');
          window.location.replace("main.html");
          return false;
    });
});
```

**Summarized:** When I click the button then it produces a alert and it will take me to main.html,, but if I go back to the page with this button then it won't do the alert nor the page changing anymore..

**ANWSER:**
instead of using:

`window.location.replace("main.html");`

I used:

```
$.mobile.changePage('main.html');
```

This because i use Jquery Mobile.

I thank Valjas also for the extra information on navigating.

Comment: it's local, im building an jquery mobile app(with phonegap).

Comment: I see. Let me see what I can do with JSFiddle...

Comment: did you try to debug using chrome or firebug. did you include jquery on the second page you are referring to.

Comment: yes i tried with chrome, but i get Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: and with firebug on firefox it won't go to another page if i click the button(also have a redirect in button function)

Comment: Maybe it's a markup issue. Have you checked in the page source that `#deleteSubmit` is really unique? Maybe it selects another DOM node then.

Comment: It seems to work... http://jsfiddle.net/howderek/ZBMkg/

Comment: it works but if i go to another page and then back, then the function doesnt work anymore

Comment: What do you mean by "go to another page and back"? Are you really visiting new URLs or are you just loading data using Ajax? We really need more markup and script to solve this, otherwise we can just guess.

Comment: How are you going 'back' to the original page? `window.location.replace` is supposed to replace the current page in session history, meaning that going to `main.html` and then clicking back would not return you to the original page with this button.

Comment: for example i have a header logo, if i click that then it will take me back to the index.html page with the button

Comment: you are runnig your application on a server( even local ) or jsut from the local file system ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>You're using `window.location.replace` which replaces the HTML in the current file with the HTML from the file you link to. You need to use `window.location.href` which will instead go to the other page.</s>

More info here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp

-- Update --

The format is different then on `window.location.replace`.

```
window.location.href = 'main.html';
```

If you still have problems with that than try:

```
window.open('main.html', _blank);
```

That will open the page in a new tab.

-- Update --

Since you're using jQuery Mobile, rather than going about it with jQuery click bind, you should just use the jQuery Mobile API.

Here are a few pages that should be helpful:

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/pages/link-formats.html

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/pages/link-formats.html#docs-navmodel.html

http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-navmodel.html

Comment: Did you try clearing your browser cache? I know for a fact window.location.href works. I use it all of the time.

Comment: Updated answer with a few examples to try.

Comment: Doesn't work, im building this app with phonegap and i use jquery + jquerymobile..

Answer (score 2):

Using `window.location.replace()` is a mistake as @jackwanders said.

Using this variable sends an HTTP request that isn't registered in the browser (or PhoneGap) history. Your app will still think it is inside `index.html` even if you clicked on `#btnSubmit`.

The solution is to use another function: `window.location.href = "main.html"`

<strike>Also, you don't need to write your binding inside the `document.ready` function. This is only useful if you want to perform an action as soon as the page has loaded -- but since you wait further on that the user clicks the link, you don't need it</strike>

Comment: Actually, your comments regarding `document.ready` are incorrect. The `onload` event is for performing an action right after the page is loaded. `document.ready` ensures that the page is fully loaded before making the script available, which is best practice.

Comment: thanks @Valjas I didn't know about that distinction. (post edited)